# external drive only shows up on reboot (invisible in device and drive manager)

Tags: windows-10

Not visible in device manager, disk manager either when plugging in after reboot. Tried unassigning drive letter too.

This only happens on my work laptop (Lenovo thinkpad). Changing usb port doesn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using some other ext. drives on that laptop? - Try reinstalling the corresponging drivers. Can you see it with **diskpart**?

Comment: What is the disk file system?